# Java thread-pool not executing run command

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a strange situation. I have a ThreadPool of 1 core worker and 5 max workers. I have provided a blocking queue of 5000 items max. Whenever I submit a task to this pool it just gets queued. Nothing happens. No error, no exception. I have added ex-handlers in all possible places. Runnable object gets initialized but run() method never executes. Please help

Threadpool:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(5000);
private ThreadPoolExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 5, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
```

Task insertion:

I am reading n number of records from DB, splitting it into chunks and feeding chunk start-no and end-no to workers.

```
do {
   try {
        taskExecutor.execute(new EmailWorker(lowerOffset, upperOffset));
        logger.trace("Added work: seq:"+lowerOffset+" to seq no:"+upperOffset+" to executor pool");
        lowerOffset = lowerOffset + (batchSize-1) + 1;
        upperOffset = lowerOffset + (batchSize-1);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch(RejectedExecutionException ree) {
        logger.trace("Too many work items. Pausing for a while, let Email workers catch up."+ree.getMessage());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }

   } catch (CriticalException ex) {
        throw ex;
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      logger.error("", ex);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error("",ex);
   }            
} while(upperOffset <= maxSeqNo);
```

In the worker, I have below structure in run method. Since I have try block at the start itself any error happening inside it should be caught anyhow.

```
public void run() {
    logger.trace("email worker work started");
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        //
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException sq) {
        kafkaLogger.error(sq.getClass() + " :: " + sq.getMessage());
        logger.error(sq.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception sq) {
        kafkaLogger.error(sq.getClass() + " :: " + sq.getMessage());
        logger.error(sq.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This is the output of ThreadPool

```
[2018-01-15 19:03:46] :: TRACE :: EmailSupervizor:156 - [Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
[2018-01-15 19:03:51] :: TRACE :: EmailSupervizor:157 - [Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 0]
[2018-01-15 19:03:56] :: TRACE :: EmailSupervizor:160 - [Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 3, completed tasks = 0]
[2018-01-15 19:03:61] :: TRACE :: EmailSupervizor:156 - [Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 4, completed tasks = 0]
```

Comment: Seems like EmailWorker swallow errors. Can you post EmailWorker ?

Comment: I have try block on the first line of run() in EmailWorker. So a global exception handler is there. Also in case of swallowing tasks should reduce. Here this doesn't happen. Also I have some log string on the first line of run(), that also doesn't get printed.

Comment: including catch all `Throwable`?

Comment: yes, please see the edits. I cannot post whole code here, but a broad structure I could.

Comment: can downvoter explain what is wrong with my question?

Comment: I *think* your first thread is failing/blocking somewhere in your worker. With your corePoolSize set at 1, this means the executor will always prefer to queue new requests rather than create new threads (this is documented). Try setting both core and max pool size to 5 and see if the observed behaviour changes.

Comment: @AndyBrown I have added a logging line in the very first statement of run method. Even that doesn't get printed. So it's not like it's getting stuck somewhere inside, run itself doesn't seem to be getting called.

Comment: What was the output from the thread pool when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Dump threads please

Comment: @Shades88 the problem has been solved or not?